# Send Data through Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I am trying to send data from one file to another for an app. On the file that has the data, I create the intent as follows.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), scoring_two.class);
   i.putExtra("Test",Cv);
dicstr_twotank_frag.this.startActivity(i);
```

Where Cv is the value I want to send. The scoring_two is the fragment for the code where I want to send the data. It looks like this:

```
public class scoring_two extends FragmentActivity{
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
  }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rel5);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
  }
}
```

I do not know if I need to have this intent part here, but when I do, I do not know how to send the data to the scoring.java file. So far, if I try the same intent line, Android Studio highlights 'getIntent' in red and says it 'Cannot resolve the method.'

Comment: I don’t know the solution of your answer. but you should really need to read [Code Conventions for the Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: From where u need to send data ? fragment to activity or activity to fragment  ?

Comment: I have the data in one activity, and had to open the fragment of the scoring screen in order to have it open the layout of the scoring and everything. CV is a variable that I was just trying to send so that I could figure out the syntax for the code. Someone else is working on the code for the scoring, I just need to send the results.